# What model is this Weller pencil soldering iron?

Tags: identification, soldering

I have this old Weller soldering iron that was issued to me at my first job in the early 80's. It has a lot of sentimental value to me. I was going to order some new tips and the one that is on it currently is attached very well.

What is the model? How can I disassemble it? The heating element looked okay, but there was some sort of ceramic in the metal tube that shattered as I pulled it off.

[image]

After reading some of the comments, let me clarify. I have done I lot of searching. I have found a few that look close, the difference is how the tip is attached. This one is screwed on.
[image]

I tried to back into the model based on the heating element. I found this description, Ungar 127S. According to the picture, I don't think the heating element is broken. The ceramic looks like it came out of the metal tube. The picture shows a piece still in the tube. I wonder if it has something to do with the temperature control and/or directing the heat more toward the tip.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The ceramic is where the heater is, and you broke it. You don't have to use an iron with sentimental value. It sounds like the iron had a good run - you could always hang it up, put a plaque saying "my first soldering iron", and get something newer. Is this one even temperature-controlled?

Comment: Weller only makes one model in that colour with a black grip and three prong plug: W60P3. https://www.weller-tools.com/us/en/industrial-soldering/products/soldering-irons You can do a Ship of Theseus with the new innards and the outer handle.

Comment: @user253751:  It's most likely a magnastat iron, so it is regulated.

Comment: You're getting into the "This axe has been in my family for five generations. It's had two replacement heads and five handles" territory.

Comment: I tried to address some of the comments by editing the OP. @DKNguyen, that was close. I followed the like and thought you nailed it. The tip is different. I wonder if it is the same model and Weller changed how the tip is mounted.

Comment: @user253751 I do own a solder/hot air, infrared station. I also have some cheaper temperature-controlled pencil-style soldering irons.  I never knew what the wattage was and am surprised that the old boy is only 27 watts. But that little guy would solder heavier gauge wire better than my Craftsman Soldering Gun.  Looking at the W60P3, granted 60 watts, for $123 it might even make financial sense to try and fix it. There still is something satisfying about using the 40+ year-old soldering iron from time to time. :-)

Comment: ok, in this case it looks like the heater is not broken

Comment: @user253751 Sometimes questions/answers help you refine your question. It is a case of you can't see the second mountain till after you climb the first. :-)

Whatever the ceramic is along the inside of the tube, did shatter and fall out. I wish I would have taken a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ground pin has broken off or has been removed from the plug- that is not ideal and you should replace the plug if you intend on using the iron as a soldering iron.

The Model 127S 27W heater (apparently now broken) is easily available (as of this writing, anyway) for a very reasonable price.

I really don't think this kind of soldering iron is temperature controlled, but I am not 100% sure. It does not match either type I have here- WP35 (a nasty and originally cheap Weller 120V type which is not controlled and which has a 2-pin cord) or WTCP (low voltage controlled via. Magnestat). If it clunks during operation and there is a digit embossed into the back of the tip such as '6' (for 600°F) it is likely the latter (assuming it has the correct tip installed). Weller et al. have been around a long while and there have been [changes to the various products](https://www.electronicsurplus.com/ungar-1333-soldering-tools-heating-element-110v-ac-dc-37-1-2w#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Weller%20bought%20Ungar%20a,by%20Cooper%2C%20then%20Apex%20Industries.). I can still get parts for my 20-40 year-old tools (though they are long ago no longer made), but there are also probably ones that were less popular.

> Weller bought Ungar a while back, and Weller was swallowed by Cooper,
> then Apex Industries.

Here is a spare heater for a Magnestat low-voltage iron- it is a hollow metal tube rather than a ceramic cylinder and it looks nothing like yours:

[image]

While you can certainly replace the heater and put a new line cord or plug on the unit you have, it was never a great soldering iron for electronics work and you'd do better to replace it with a modern controlled-temperature type.

Comment: I added some more pictures while you were posting. They crossed in the mail. :-) Anyway, they are different.  I understand the concern about the ground. The reason it was removed, is to prevent a ground loop. Why, I was an electronic cash register tech. We would replace a soldered-on rechargeable battery while under power. The reason for doing it under power is the battery protected some CMOS memory that you did not want to lose. A second option was to use a battery with alligator clips. There were a couple of test points you could attach it to and try it that way. If one popped off... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Spehro gave a good try. I've gone back to an old local catalog (Spehro, you might recognize Electrosonic) that displayed three type of Ungar soldering irons:

- Standard line
- 3-wire line
- Princess

All three could take thread-in tips. Princess was a small iron, I recall it took 1/8" dia. tips.
Paul's photo looks similar to "3-wire line". It takes 120V AC heat cartridges of different powers:

- 127-S is a 27W heating element temp range 650-750 F for Ungar model 127 iron
- 135-S is a 35W heating element temp range 750-850 F for Ungar model 135 iron
- 145-S is a 45W heating element temp range 900-1000 F for Ungar model 145 iron

A threaded body replacement part # 130 for heating element. Perhaps the metal shroud?
A handle and chord assembly part # 136
A heat reflector part # 129

Somewhat unclear to me what thread-in tips were used. Some are 1/8" dia. Others 3/16" dia.

---

Since these items are ancient (practically antique) brand, hope this doesn't constitute forbidden advertising. Have an old Ungar 45W that takes 1/4" thread-on tips that may be of different form from OP's. But the two-pin ceramic heat cartridge looks similar.